# k-NN algorithm for detect lines in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, line, detection, knn

I have a gray scale image made by a unicolour background with some bright spot, some of which organized in lines.
I want detect these lines basing on the density of pixels and so I thought to the k-NN algorithm.

Is it a reasonable idea?

If so, I identify each pixel by its position and intensity (3 values total). How could I detect these lines on a 2D graph?

Comment: k-NN doesn't sound directly relevant. Line detection is a much-studied problem. Start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_detection and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Comment: Can you please show the image? It is not completely obvious what "organized in lines" mean. You might be looking for **edge detection** or for some kind of **linear regression**, or something else; the problem is very unclear without the image. If possible, you could also include a second image of what you want as an output (for instance, manually add red lines where lines should be detected).